# How can I have a random phase for each note played with an AKOscillatorBank?

Tags: c++, swift, audiokit

I am using an `AKMIDINode` linked to an `AKOscillatorBank`. I would like that each time a note is played by `AKOscillatorBank`, the phase of the wavetable is randomly selected. It seams that `AudioKit` do not provide a such feature. I had a quick look at the C++ implementation, deep to `AKBankDSPKernel`, bit it is not clear to me how independent the synthesis of different notes on a single oscillator are.

Would it be possible to overload in swift part of `AKOscillatorBank` to make each midi note use a different offset when looking at the `AKTable` ?

This feature can drastically improve the sounding of the attack of a chord when using "warms" wave table and slow/inexistant attack time, especially sawtooth. It will greatly improve the sound of my product.

Answer (score 1):

The oscillator bank kernel contains a `NoteState` struct which holds the oscillator state for each voice, I believe. I suppose you could use a `sp_tabread_compute` to read the samples from a wavetable (as in `AKPhaseDistortionOscillator)` and randomize its offset in the noteOn function.